# Loop around an array forward and backward

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

This is my function to loop forward from a given index. I am looking for a behaviour to go from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4, then go back to 1 and repeat.

```
def forward(letter)
  arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  if arr.find_index(letter) < 3
    arr[arr.find_index(letter) + 1]
  elsif arr.find_index(letter) == 3
    arr[0]
  end
end

forward('d') # => 'a'
forward('b') # => 'c'
```

and I have the counterpart to loop backwards.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What is `number` here? It's not shown.

Comment: What if `number` isn't an element of the array? You're going to get an error.

Comment: sorry corrected

Comment: What is `arrs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of searching through the array every time, you could use a hash:

```
def forward(letter)
  {'a'=>'b', 'b'=>'c', 'c'=>'d', 'd'=>'a'}[letter]
end

forward('d') #=> "a"
forward('b') #=> "c"
```

You can easily build such hash from an array using [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`rotate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-rotate):

```
arr = %w[a b c d]
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

hash = arr.zip(arr.rotate).to_h
#=> {"a"=>"b", "b"=>"c", "c"=>"d", "d"=>"a"}
```

[`invert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-i-invert) the hash to move backward:

```
hash.invert
#=> {"b"=>"a", "c"=>"b", "d"=>"c", "a"=>"d"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def forward(letter)
  arr = ['a','b','c','d']
  i = arr.find_index(letter)
  arr[(i + 1) % arr.length]
end
```

Comment: This does however simply return the element itself. `arr[i % arr.length]` should be `arr[(i + 1) % arr.length]` for the other direction simply use `i - 1` the rest can stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this is with a cycle-enumerator and a loop.

```
def forward letter
  enum = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].cycle
  loop {
    n = enum.next
    break enum.peek if n == letter
  }
end

forward 'a' #=> 'b'
forward 'b' #=> 'c'
forward 'c' #=> 'd'
forward 'd' #=> 'a'
```

Comment: `enum.each_cons(2).find {|a,_| a == letter}.last` is nice too and avoids the `loop` and `break`

Comment: @engineersmnky Great idea to use `each_cons` and using `find` is more semantic.

Comment: Yeah if you wanted to go in both directions then `each_cons(3)` and check the middle as a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
def forward(number)
  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  return arr[number % arr.size]
end
```

Comment: Yes! thank you and is there a way I can tell it to go the other way around? 
4, 3 , 2 ,1 then back to 4? or would you recommend I have a separate array for that?

Comment: actually this only works on numbers, maybe it is not what I am looking for

Comment: `def backward(number); forward(-number); end`
This works no matter the content of the array.

Comment: @draganstankovic I believe this comment "actually this only works on numbers, maybe it is not what I am looking for" is referring to the fact that the OP cannot call `forward('a')` because this will raise an `TypeError no implicit conversion of String into Integer` because `'a' % 4` will use `String#%` instead thus returning a `String`

Comment: I see the update to the question now. Was busy meantime but it seems like others covered it :)